# Getting "Can't connect to MySQL server on '203.171.xx.xx' (13) " when trying to connect to remote sqlserver with python in cgi

Tags: python, mysql, sql, cgi, mysql-python

When tried to connect to mysql database through python MySQLdb getting following err:

```
File "/var/www/cgi-bin/add_user.py", line 39, in &lt;module&gt;
addEntry(prop.text.strip())
File "/var/www/cgi-bin/add_user.py", line 19, in addEntry
  db = mdb.connect(host="203.171.xx.xx", user="usrone", passwd="psdone", db="test", port=3306)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
  super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '203.171.xx.xx' (13)")
```

python code used to connect is as below:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
db = mdb.connect(host="203.171.xx.xx", user="usrone", passwd="psdone", db="test", port=3306)
```

this code is working when used from python command prompt however it fails with above error when used from cgi script.

I have checked the wireshark captures and noticed that command failed without even connecting to remote mysql server.

Apache server version : Apache/2.2.15
I have given all permissions (chmod 777) to python script file.

Any suggestion as to why this might happen?

Comment: to test the environment written a simple tcp client from cgi script and tried to connect to local db and even that fails with error "Permission denied"!

Answer (score 0):

I did some troubleshooting around MySQL (with redmine) on Friday :).

Make sure that the MySQL instance has a user that is "allowed" to listen to that port. Mostly you will see the users refer to ::1 or 127.0.0.1 or localhost - or in fact "your client's" computer.

Also under MySQL.ini make sure the remove the line binding it to 127.0.0.1 (just search for 127.0.0.1) and comment out with # (you will know it when you see it).  That worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the response.. it turned out that this script is working when used from python prompt.. but only failing when used from cgi script.

Comment: I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: cgi tends to run "out of process".  Confirm the context that it is running under to see if it is working.

Comment: sorry for asking a nob question. but how could i confirm that?

Comment: Then I can definitely not assist any further.  I know Ubuntu, Xenix, sco - intermediate.

Comment: how would you do it in ubuntu?

Comment: Also: It is probably in /etc/apache. It is usually called httpd.conf, but on my system is apache2.conf.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that apache did not have permission to connect to mysql

try this :

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```